# Go automatically to another page using html

Tags: php, html, redirect

I have two pages, a html that send value to a php page, and than, the php page returns the result in a div, in the html page.

In the first test it has only a message with error, and in the else clause it must redirect to another html page, so the script in the php page will be shown in html. I've used javascript but it doesn't do it for me.

This is all the codes that i've used:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
{
    echo" Code erron&eacute; ";
}
else
{
    header('location:infosInt.html');
    //echo "<script> window.open('infosInt.html')</script>";
    //echo "<script> window.location = 'infosInt.html'</script>";
}
```

**EDIT**

my html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery-ui.js" charset="ISO-8859-1"></script>
          <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js" charset="ISO-8859-1"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.crypt.js" ></script>
   <LINK rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="android.css">

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <script>

function connexion(evt)
{
var x=document.getElementById('code');
var cde = x.value;
 var str = $().crypt({
  method: "md5",
  source: cde
  });
if (cde=="")
  {
 // document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  var url ="http://localhost/filename/page.php";
  var params="q="+ str;
        xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
       xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        xmlhttp.send(params);     

};
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="login">
      <p></p>
    <form method="" action="" id= "codeform"  onsubmit="connexion();return false;">
     <p> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp</p>

      <input type="password"   id="code" ></p>

      <p class="submit"><input type="submit"  id="connect" value="Connexion" ></p>

    </form>
  <div id ="txtHint"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is page.php:

```
<?php

$host     = "localhost";
$port     = port;
$socket   = "";
$user     = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname   = "base";


$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket);
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

$q =$con->real_escape_string($_POST['q']);

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");

$sql="query where column ='".$q."'"; // ex
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
  {
 echo" Code erron&eacute; ";
  }
else
{
echo"<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5; URL=infosInt.html'></head>";}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: So, what seems to be the problem then?

Comment: Add an `exit;` behind the line `header(...)`

Comment: And if you (really) want to use "HTML" as you said in your subject, use something like `<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://google.com/"></head>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- the problem is in my html page when i execute the form it doesn't send me to the page i want

Comment: @ImanHjrt It would be best if you could post your entire code, and any JS you may have. The problem may lie elsewhere.

Comment: @ImanHjrt I have seen cases where, if there wasn't a space between the colon and the filename/page itself, would fail. Try either `header('Location: infosInt.html');` or add the full URL `header('Location: http://www.your_site.com/infosInt.html');`

Comment: didn't work . YES i mean html , because that php code is gonna be sent into a div in my html . so i need that redirection to be understood by html

Comment: okey, ill update my post

Comment: `header('location...` won't work since "Location" needs to be capitalized : `header('Location: http://www.website.com/page');`

Comment: @Brewal didn't work either

Comment: Do you really need to support IE5/6 or did you just copy&paste some AJAX code? Besides that: You are using jQuery. So you can use it for AJAX stuff, too!

Comment: Are you calling this with ajax ? 'cause if you call a php script with ajax, an `header('Location: ...`);` won't do anything. If you don't, make sure you have no html sent before the header (such as space i.e.)

Comment: Well @ThiefMaster is right. Forget IE < 7 (or include some support for netscape)

Comment: @ImanHjrt You're running this off of `localhost` and not via `WWW`? If so, from what I can tell by `var url ="http://localhost/filename/page.php";` then try to go about it this way then `header('Location: http://localhost/infosInt.html');` or depending on where your `infosInt.html` is located.

Comment: yes i need to support the IE5/6 , if not the xmlhttprequest won't work for me .
@Fred-ii- i didn't understand, i have already declared the url var .... and did the header location and nothing happens . i only want to go to another page. you can tell me any solution

Comment: @ImanHjrt Have you tried `header('Location: http://localhost/infosInt.html');` instead of `header('Location: infosInt.html');` ? Depending on the location of `infosInt.html`

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I think I understood that the php script was called with ajax. So there's no way to do a redirection in it. I have answered with solution including a simple server response handling... I don't really know if it is what the OP expected

Comment: @Brewal Your answer makes sense and did think of it also, using a `window.location = "infosInt.html"` in the controller. Now I'm suspecting something may be in `.htaccess` preventing the redirection. This one's hard to wrap my head around to tell you the truth. I think the OP will need to re-think the whole thing, and drop support for older versions of IE. Key-ripes, it's 2013 here, not 1995 ;-)

Comment: no i'm not usinh a htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, you are calling your php script with ajax, so you can't use `header('Location: ...')` or an html redirection. You should return a flag in your php script and test it when you get the response with javascript :

PHP (at the end of `page.php`):

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
{
    echo "Code erron&eacute;";
}
else
{
    echo "redirect"; // the flag
}
```

Javascript (on the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` event) :

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    if (xmlhttp.responseText == 'redirect') { // if flag is sent we redirect
        document.location.href = 'infosInt.html';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is logic ,I've put it , but when i click the button it's kinda disappear for seconds and appears the same page nothing aded..

Comment: But the url isn't pointing to `infosInt.html` after the redirection ?

Comment: nothing happend , it only like disapear for 2 secondes with a white page than come back . but your code seems logic i don't know where is the problem

Comment: Where did you put the html that you have paste in your question ?

Comment: i don't think the problem is that. because even when i put a wrong utpot the 'code errone' msg do not appear . it also make the page dissapear for seconds like flash and come back

Comment: Are you sure of your query ? Well, does this even works without the `onsubmit` event on the form ? (You will have to put `name="q"` on your input.

Comment: @Brewal Strangely that, I was thinking the same thing (again). I noticed the OP has `$q =$con->real_escape_string($_POST['q']);` which is incorrect, since is using `mysqli`, should be using `$q =$con->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['q']);` Unless OP has a function called `real_escape_string` elsewhere that we don't see.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah the OP doesn't seems to have a good understanding of what he's trying to do. I'm out too !

Comment: @Brewal Well, as the 'ol saying goes: "It's been a slice...". Cheers!

Comment: @Fred-ii- the syntax is correct what you've mentionned didn't work for  me .

Comment: @Brewal , when i pass the value in the url of the php page it works fine , so my query is correct . and i know what i'm doing . everything is correct in my code , i only need to redirect the page to another page . thanks for helping !!!!!

Comment: @ImanHjrt I suggest you re-think your entire code and drop support for older browsers. With all due respect, we are in the 21st century and not the 1990s. We are in an age of iPhones and not 5000lbs calculators. You're mixing new syntax with old, how do you expect both to successfully work together?

Comment: Okey , but it's not that my problem right now. and doesn not change anything , i only wnat to redirect my page , what @Brewal have put seems to me logic, but i don't know it doesn't work...

Comment: @ImanHjrt Have you not [read my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881531/go-automatically-to-another-page-using-html/18882318?noredirect=1#comment27869455_18882318)? `real_escape_string` is invalid, that's why your query is failing and probably the cause of not redirecting.

Comment: Bon, j'ai fini avec ce mec. Salut! (je m'en lave les mains) ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes , i've read it, and i've tried to do what you'v said . again that gives me errors ! what i'm putting is the final solution that worked for me ...

Comment: i was talking about the $q =$con->real_escape_string($_POST['q']);